# Sum of Matrix Norms and boundedness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $N$, show that there is a constant $C$ such that $$||I + tN + \cdots + t^n N^n|| \le Ct^n$$
for all sufficiently large $t$.

I am not sure how to show this. I am guessing I am supposed to use sub-multiplicative norms here, but I do not see how doing such a thing would show that the normed sum is less than or equal to $Ct^n$.

Also if someone could edit the "<=" symbol into a less than or equal to sign that would be greatly appreciated, I am quite inexperienced with MathJax

Comment: hint : $$||I+tN+t^2N^2+...+t^nN^n|| \leq ||I||+||tN||+||t^2N^2||+...+||t^nN^n|| \\\leq 1+|t|||n||+|t^2||\|N^2||+...+|t^n|||N^n||\\ \leq 1+|t|||N||+t^2||n||^2+...+|t^n|||N||^n=\frac{1(1-|t^{n+1}|||N||^{n+1})}{1-|t|||N||}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\| I \| + \| N \| + \ldots + \|N^n\|)=C$, then for $t >>1$, $t^n >>1,t,\ldots , t^{n-1}$, now use the triangle inequality, and the fact that $t^n$ is larger than the rest of coefficients. It's rather immediate.